# Ubuntu 14.04 built in webcam not being detected

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, camera

Hello I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and my webcam is not recognized. It used to work fine but recently it is not working. I got my screen replaced by dell and also the motherboard and heatsinks for a different issue.

Here is my lsusb output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:21f9 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also ran this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

that people said would help but I got this error:

```
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.16.0-53-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-53-generic
Error! The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch. This indicates that it should not be built.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a hardware issue. I had the entire screen assembly replaced and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

Section 5 (driver install) of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam

http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Webcam-HOWTO/hardware.html

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstall cheese and config files:**

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cheese
```

**Reinstall cheese:**

```
sudo apt-get install cheese
```

**Reboot your computer**

This works perfectly for a Dell Notebook using Ubuntu 16.04 with dual boot